# Split string and exclude last split

Tags: c#, string, split

Is there anyway for me to split a string and exclude the last split?

My data looks like this: `data1,data2,data3,` and so if I split the element the last element in the array will be empty, so I would just prefer to exclude it from the split.

Right now I have this:

```
serialNumbers = delimitedSerials.ToString().Split(',');
```

Granted I know I can just leave it and in my `for` loop just know to skip the last element, but was wondering if there was a simple way to just exclude it at the time of splitting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can split it using the StringSplitOptions parameter:

```
data.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: I was about to post an answer using linq and LastIndexOf... but this is just the proper built-in way.. :)

Comment: oh wow, didn't know that they had that option. That is pretty cool, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's the other overload of the split function. It's really handy, and you can split on more than one char.

Comment: Interesting, so if I wanted to split on spaces as well I could just do `{ ',', ' '}`?

Comment: But a warning is due here. If the empty entries are inside the string this will remove them and not sure if this is what the OP expects

Comment: @Steve what do you mean by empty entries inside the string?

Comment: He means that if you have fe. `data1,,data3,`, the second value will be removed as well. Edit: It'll return string[2] with data1 and data3 onyl

Comment: As @Reynevan says. RemoveEmptyEntries in the context above will return an array of two elements (data1 and data3).

Comment: Ahh I see, really I think that should be fine, because the way we scan in our serials the scanner always puts a `,` after the serial number. So unless it is a blank serial number we wouldn't have that issue.

Comment: Just in case you ever need something that removes only the last value, and leaves other empty values be: `data.Split(',').Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse().ToArray();`. This Reverses the collection; skips the first (last normally) one; reverses i back and returns as `string[]`

Answer (score 2):

Below code has a Linq where clause to exclude the empty data

```
string input ="data1,data2,data3,";

var output = input.Split(',').Where(value => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value));

foreach(string data in output)
    Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Comment: Why do that when it is  standard options for `Split` already? (Note that this also does not answer question as asked in the title, which make it even stranger suggestion).

Comment: Thanks! it is an interesting suggestion, and good to know, but going with the other method.